# Need help with sentence construction

Tags: questions, reflexive-pronouns

I need some help with sentence grammar and I hope you can help me.

> What is your biggest goal in life? Is it to write a book, find a fulfilling job or find a love of your life?

Can I start second sentence like this? ("Is it to write....")

Comment: Yes, of course. "It" is a pro-form here referring to "your biggest goal in life", so the second sentence means "Is your biggest goal in life to write a book, find a fulfilling job or find the love of your life?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second sentence is fine

> *Is it to* write a book, find a fulfilling job or find ***the*** love of your life?

is  a combination of

> *Is it to* write a book?
>   *Is it* to find a fulfilling job? or
>   *Is it* to find ***the*** love of your life?

You can start your sentence it with "Is it...?" since it is a question. However I would change "a" to "the".